# Calculating ticks from given year (Mathematical Approach)

Tags: c#, .net-core

I've been trying to convert a given date to ticks using the following formula and since I've just begun writing this function I do not yet consider the `month` and `day` values :

```
public static long DateToTicks(int year, int month, int day) {
     var leapYears = (year - 1) / 4;
     var result = ((year - 1) * 365 * OneDay.Ticks) + (leapYears * OneDay.Ticks);
     return result;
}
```

The `OneDay.Ticks` is a constant here whose value is `3600 * 24 * 1000 * 10000`.

The problem I have faced is that, when I calculate ticks from day zero (i.e. 0001-01-01, 0002-01-01) it works fine until I reach year 101 where I get an additional day! I compare my result against the value returned by the `DateTime` struct in `.Net Core`. For example:

```
var myResult = DateToTicks(100, 01, 01);
var dateTimeResult = new DateTime(100,01,01).Ticks;
```

Until this date, `myResult == dateTimeResult` is always true, but when I enter the next century I see that the result returned by `DateTime` struct is one day behind, and as I enter another century this value doubles.

However, I know that in 101 years, there are 25 leap years which means that I have to multiply `75` years by `365` and the rest by `366` and then add them together, and I cannot understand why my result is different from dot net's  `DateTime` result.

What's the problem with my approach? Given that month and day would be not important (always set to `01`).

Comment: Your leap year calculation is wrong. https://www.timeanddate.com/date/leapyear.html

Comment: @xxbbcc: why? what's wrong with that?

Comment: As you are reinventing the wheel, you have missed out a few things like, leap years don't occur every 4 years, the rules are more complicated than that.  You are also missing the fact that calendars have changed in the last 2000 years, whole months were removed in the middle ages.

Comment: @Neil: I'm not reinventing it, I want to use this code later in another programing language, now testing it to make sure it works fine.

Comment: The dot net library source is available online, why not use that as a resource?  The calculation you are trying to implement is hard.

Comment: source here https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetime.cs,df6b1eba7461813b

Comment: @Neil: You are trying to say the right thing, but who has the nerve to take a look at that large code? I'm looking for a shortcut that why I'm here.

Comment: the code is very readable, nicely hyperlink, easy to browse (its not a raw repository)

Comment: It depends if you want to do it correctly, or implement a shortcut that is wrong

Comment: @pm100: You read it and use it on my behalf and have whatever fun you want with that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your logic for leap year calculation to this and it works well:

```
var leapYears = ((year - 1) / 4) - (year / 400 > 0 ? ((year) / 100) - (((year) / 400)) : ((year - 1) / 100)) + (year % 100 == 0 && year % 400 != 0 ? 1 : 0) + (year == 100 || year == 200 || year == 300 ? -1 : 0);
```

Answer (score 3):

since you dont seem to want to look at the c# code. I looked there for you - took me 1 minute

```
    private static long DateToTicks(int year, int month, int day) {     
        if (year >= 1 && year <= 9999 && month >= 1 && month <= 12) {
            int[] days = IsLeapYear(year)? DaysToMonth366: DaysToMonth365;
            if (day >= 1 && day <= days[month] - days[month - 1]) {
                int y = year - 1;
                int n = y * 365 + y / 4 - y / 100 + y / 400 + days[month - 1] + day - 1;
                return n * TicksPerDay;
            }
        }
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(null, Environment.GetResourceString("ArgumentOutOfRange_BadYearMonthDay"));
    }
```

and

```
   public static bool IsLeapYear(int year) {
        if (year < 1 || year > 9999) {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("year", Environment.GetResourceString("ArgumentOutOfRange_Year"));
        }
        Contract.EndContractBlock();
        return year % 4 == 0 && (year % 100 != 0 || year % 400 == 0);
    }
```

here is the direct link

https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetime.cs,891f8af5025ab2f3

Answer (score -1):

A simple divide by 4 is not the correct way to determine a leap year.

Here is a way to test for a leap year:

> The year can be evenly divided by 4;
>
> If the year can be evenly divided by 100, it is NOT a leap year, unless;
>
> The year is also evenly divisible by 400. Then it is a leap year.

So, 1900 is not a leap year, but 2000 is a leap year.

Comment: Which year exactly? Do you know already, or do you wanna enter a loop to find out? I'm looking for a pure mathematical formula.